# Remove items from a list by innerHTML in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, asp-classic

I'm new here and I'm stuck in my project...

I need exclude items from a cart on an ecommerce...

This cart is showed inside a iframe from Fancybox.

It works, but visually in Chrome, it doesn't. In Firefox and IE it's work fine...

I have my items in divs named like div_1, div_2, div_3...

```
<div id="div_1">
   content...
</div>
<div id="div_2>
   content...
</div>
<div id="div_3>
   content...
</div>
```

To scroll the page, I put all content inside a main div with style.

```
style="overflow: hidden; width:820px; height:auto;"
```

Because the scroll is controled by the iframe(auto) and my main div there is defined value of widht, and height is auto to fit with my content...

Inside the divs, I have a img from product, name, price and a remove button with this JS:-

```
onClick="removeItem(<%=arrayIndexdiv%>)"
```

And the function:-

```
<script>
    function removeItem( itemid ) {
        document.getElementById('div_' + itemid ).innerHTML = "";
    }
</script>
```

In other words, the funcion simply erase the div, excluding them from the page...

When my list itens is bigger than the iframe size, the vert scrollbar appears.

When I click on remove, the iten is gonne corretly, in all brownsers, but in Chrome, the size of iframe not change, and I have a blank space above all my items, before the footer.

In IE and Mozilla it's ok, the space doesn't appears, but in Chrome it is there...

I don't know if I can put here the URL to help more? If I can, please tell me!

Can anyone help me?

Sorry my english!

Thank you GUYS!

Comment: Do you really have `<div_1>` instead of `<div id="div_1">`? Please fix you question to show the real HTML.

Comment: You also shouldn't use `overflow: hidden` if you want this div to be scrollable. Use `overflow: scroll` instead.

Comment: ok, i edited... its correct now, sorry! by the way, I put overflow: scroll but not change anything in any browser!

Comment: Setting the innerHTML to "" doesn't remove the element, only its content.

Comment: i believe its a bug in Chrome, because if i just click in any area of my iframe (not necessary in REMOVE) the scrollbar is resized to bigger... very strange!

Comment: @user2793679 can you provide a fiddle? how does it resized?

Comment: can you try my page: http://megastillo.com/teste.asp and click sometimes in ADCIONAR AO CARRINHO in products and after in FINALIZAR

Comment: im using hidden on my main div, because the scroll is by the iframe... the main div takes the 100% of height and the iframe control de scrollbar... if i put auto, 3 scrollbars is appears on my iframe. i can disable scrolling on iframe, but i can scroll my div just verticaly???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you you want to remove the element from the `DOM` not just override the content of `div`.

The `innerHTML` property sets or gets the HTML syntax describing the element's descendants.
In your case you are just setting the `div` content:

```
document.getElementById('div_' + itemid ).innerHTML = "";
```

If you want to remove element from `DOM`:

```
function removeItem( itemid ) {
  var element = document.getElementById('div_' + itemid ); // will return element
  element.parentNode.removeChild(element); // will remove the element from DOM
}
```

Also `style="overflow: hidden; width:820px; height:auto;"` will hide the overflowing `div` but will not scroll it.

If you want it to scroll you can set `overflow:scroll`.

Comment: i did it, and works, visually, like the other way that i was using... but in chrome, the problem still there.. because if i just click in any area of my iframe (not necessary in REMOVE) the scrollbar is resized to bigger... very strange! try my page: http://megastillo.com/teste.asp and click sometimes in ADCIONAR AO CARRINHO in products and after in FINALIZAR

Comment: @user2793679 Hey I am sorry but I failed to address your issue.Its perfectly working fine in chrome as well.Try setting `overflow:auto`.But it really doesnt make a sense

Comment: im using hidden, because the scroll is by the iframe... the main div takes the 100% of height and the iframe control de scrollbar... if i put auto, 3 scrollbars is appears on my iframe. i can disable scrolling on iframe, but i can scroll my div just verticaly???

Comment: so you just want to scroll your `div` to scroll vertically ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is that since div tags are block elements, they are still taking up space in the parent div. Like so:

```
var element = document.getElementById("div_" + itemid); 
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

Also, this action is a little cleaner in jquery. You may want to look into it for further DOM operations.

Comment: is this interesting? as I said to the friend above, I forgot to mention the id of divs, but they exist, only here i forgot.
How do I use your example in practice?

Comment: it works too, seems more clean, but the issue persists... i believe its a bug in Chrome, because if i just click in any area of my iframe (not necessary in REMOVE) the scrollbar is resized to bigger... very strange!